# How to get access to local file name in download receiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to get file path of downloaded file, i provided receiver which works but how can i get file name/path?

**Inside onReceive**

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
    Cursor c = this.query(q); // how to get access to this since there is no instance of DownloadManager

    try {
        String filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
        Log.i("DOWNLOAD LISTENER", filePath);

    } catch(Exception e) {

    } finally {
        c.close();
    }

}
```

> Cannot resolve method query(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get ahold of a `DownloadManager` instance via the `getSystemService()` method of `Context`.

Something like this should work:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

        // get the DownloadManager instance
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        Cursor c = manager.query(q);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                Log.i("DOWNLOAD LISTENER", "file name: " + name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else {
            Log.i("DOWNLOAD LISTENER", "empty cursor :(");
        }

        c.close();
    }
}
```