# Is there a simpler way to check which download has been completed?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm currently creating an app that needs to download a couple of videos then save the local path of it on a `SQLite` database.

At first, I wanted to get the `URL` of the video I downloaded but I can't seem to find anything that discusses about it. I tried to get `COLUMN_MEDIAPROVIDER_URI` and `COLUMN_URI` from the intent passed on the `BroadcastReceiver` for `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` but they return null.

Then I found about `EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID`. But if I use that, I still need to use something like a new `HashMap` that got the `EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID` of my download and the id of the video on my `SQLite` database for checking which is which.

I'm fine with that but I want to know if there's an easier way to do the thing I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below from the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848110/how-to-get-access-to-local-file-name-in-download-receiver)

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

        // get the DownloadManager instance
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        Cursor c = manager.query(q);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                Log.i("DOWNLOAD LISTENER", "file name: " + name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else {
            Log.i("DOWNLOAD LISTENER", "empty cursor :(");
        }

        c.close();
    }
}
```

and saving the download id on my ArrayList I was able to make a simpler way to check which download is finished.

I modified it to look like this for my use case.

```
Cursor c = dlMgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query());
boolean found = false;

if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String dlFilePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
        int dlId = Integer.parseInt( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)) );

        for(int x = 0; x < vidArrLst.size(); x++){
            VideoAd va = vidArrLst.get(x);
            if(va.getDownloadId() == dlId){
                dbHelper.updateLocalPath(va.getVideoId(), dlFilePath);

                va.setLocalPath(dlFilePath);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (c.moveToNext() && !found);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "empty cursor :(");
}
```

UPDATE:

Sometimes this method will show that 2 downloads finished with the same file name which results to a video item to not have a local path. What I did is check if the local path is empty, download id is greater than 0, and if the download id is still downloading before playing a video so I can redownload a video and fix the gap and play the local file the next time the video needs to be played.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using OkHttp, as follows:

```java
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(YOUR_URL)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    // ERROR MESSAGE
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    response.body().byteStream(); // byteStream with your result.
                }
            }
        });
```

Another thing, maybe would be better if you store the videos on memory and just the address in your SQLite.

Comment: Is that code another way to make a download? I'm storing the downloaded videos currently on the Downloads folder but I'll make it be stored on an external drive then I'll save that path on my `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Yes it is, I think that the code is simpler using the OkHttp

Comment: Using that code, how do I get the local path of the downloaded file and download id of my request?

Comment: So, you'll receive a `byteStream` that you can convert and store on your device memory in the place that you want by saving it as a File